# What's the thing with empty script tags in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

To include an external JavaScript file in HTML page you would use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
```

The body of this tag is empty, yet I have to type the string `script` twice. Why isn't XML-style implicit closing tag in HTML, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/jquery-2.2.2.js" />
```

If it is valid (at least in HTML5), then how to make sure every browser supporting HTML5 (or XHTML5) can pick up on this usage?

#### EDIT

I'm gonna take this question to HTML WG. Deprecate the `src` attribute on `<script>` as it is the source of this entire confusion, with one of the two options:

- `<link>` tag instead of an empty `<script>` tag:

  ```
  <link type="text/javascript" href="images/jquery-2.2.2.js" />
  ```

  Or optionally with a `rel` attribute:

  ```
  <link rel="script" type="text/javascript" href="images/jquery-2.2.2.js" />
  ```
- PHP-style `include()` in JavaScript itself: (thus force *some* content into the tag at all times, and allow multiple scripts to be included in one `script` tag)

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">include("images/jquery-2.2.2.js");</script>
  ```

Comment: Interestingly, that actually used to work in firefox, around 2.0, but it was closed off to make XSS harder and allow more sanitizing RegExps to work correctly. i remember the changelog entry...

Comment: rough tl;dr AFAIK: an initial goal of HTML5 was to standardize what could work most reliably across browsers. This was never implemented in some browsers, and so it was excluded from HTML5 for comparability reasons. This caused the browsers that had implemented it in HTML mode to decide to drop it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: it's simpler: no tag that can have content can be self-closing via `/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omitting the closing tag for `<script>` in HTML5 is *not* permissible, according to the specs (see the Tag Omission sections):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element

Answer (score 3):

You may not omit the closing tag for the script element. If you do so, the JavaScript runtime will see the following HTML as JavaScript and error out.

The only time you may self-terminate an element tag (`<br />`) is IF that element, either doesn't have a closing tag (br, link, meta) or the closing tag is defined as optional (li, p).

Now, the reason why you must type the element with an open and closing tag is because that element ***can contain*** JavaScript, **which makes it a content element**. All content elements must always be explicitly closed, unless the spec. says otherwise.

> In reality the trailing forward-slash "/" is ignored by the HTML
>   parser. The only benefit of including it is if the markup were to be
>   parsed by an XML parser.

So, for an HTML parser, it would see this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="images/jquery-2.2.2.js" />
```

As this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="images/jquery-2.2.2.js">
```

And, it would then figure that everything that follows must be JavaScript.

Comment: I find this getting really stupid really fast. The `src` attribute and the contents of the script tag are largely mutually exclusive in real life, so allowing `<script>` self-close isn't really a bad idea as those will be almost exclusively be used to link in external scripts.

Comment: @MaxthonChan I don't disagree. But, there are a lot of 'features' in HTML that don't make a lot of sense. But, that's what XML (and XHTML) was supposed to fix, until the world decided that it didn't want XML to be the future.

Comment: Another place a fix may come in handy is `<link>` tag. Something like `<link type="text/javascript" src="images/jquery-2.2.2.js" />` can be fairly helpful, and remove the `src` attribute from `<script>` tag.

Comment: @MaxthonChan Just a little bit more insight on this. HTML was designed as a vocabulary and grammar of the SGML (Standard Generalized Markup Language), which IBM designed in the 60's. When Tim Berners-Lee created HTML, he used SGML to specify the "rules" of the HTML language. SGML requires that elements have content, don't have content or may optionally be self-terminating. Since `<script>` can contain content, it was declared as such, and thus making a closing tag required.

Comment: @MaxthonChan Another good suggestion, but again, remember that HTML, CSS and JavaScript were not all invented and implemented at the same time, so a lot of what we have today are patches upon patches that have become standards.  Netscape invented JavaScript and so they had to invent a way to inject it into the code, so they came up with `<script>` (`<link>` couldn't do it). Eventually, it worked its way into the standard.

Comment: But note that foreign elements (svg, mathML) *can* have content and be self-closing.

Comment: No It doesn't. It uses the same HTML parser. The rules are all here: w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-rules-for-parsing-tokens-in-foreign-content. Indeed invoking an XML parser wouldn't work. Namespace prefixes work differently and also note the rules in the above linked section that start "A start tag whose tag name is one of: "b", "big",..." for example.

Comment: When will SGML be considered harmful? When I think XML is 20 years, I feel sad for the slow evolution of software. Or, it's the increasing lack of education and willingness to seek quality in the IT business that keeps things broken at such a high scale.